# MySQL PHP DELETE does not work on this instance?

Tags: php, mysql, linux

```
mysql_query($sqlQ, $connection);
mysql_query("DELETE FROM Leaderboards WHERE UserName=" . $row['UserName'] . " LIMIT 1", $connection);
echo("Success3");
```

Table Information is comprised of: {UserName, Cash, Assets}.

$row['UserName'] has data as $row['Assets'] has data, INSERT works via query, yet it does not delete the row from the db table.

Tell me what I am doing wrong, this is the first time I worked with PHP & MySQL so I have no idea what I am doing.

Comment: Stop using mysql_ functions, PDO or MySQLi.  Do it.

Comment: I like your `echo("Succes3");` style, it's always a success ..

Comment: @dbf This is not all my code....I have different forms of adding a query to my db, since I am making a leaderboards.  Success2 = Adding query without deleting, vs. Success3 = Adding a query with deletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `UserName` a string? You're missing quotes.

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM Leaderboards WHERE UserName='" . $row['UserName'] . "' LIMIT 1", $connection);
```

Comment: also: mysql_escape_string that mofo.  Even better, use parameterized queries.  Also, check mysql for errors instead of ignoring any errors -- it was probably throwing a syntax error that should have given OP a hint they were doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

All mysql_* functions are deprecated and will be removed in a future version of PHP. [You should use an alternative](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

You must escape the data used in a query. Using MySQLi functions, your code would be:

```
mysqli_query($sqlQ, $connection);
mysqli_query("DELETE FROM Leaderboards WHERE UserName='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $row['UserName']) . "' LIMIT 1", $connection);
echo("Success3");
```

You are also missing quotes around the username.

I recommand not to, but if you really want to use mysql_* functions, then use:

```
mysqli_query("DELETE FROM Leaderboards WHERE UserName='" . mysql_real_escape_string($row['UserName']) . "' LIMIT 1", $connection);
```

Comment: you like that `echo("Success3")` style too don't you?

Comment: Why are you asking that? This is the OP's code, look at the question.

Comment: Well I am doing this on a small project, as long as the linux server doesn't update the PHP I am fine right? 

Besides, I can always fix it later when it breaks.  I was actually going to switch out all the mysql syntax until I figured out it was different than mysqli

Comment: @Jocelyn, I'm sorry, I won't do it again

Comment: I gave you an upvote, the other guy answered it first so I gave him the accepted.